# Sorting result based on returning object properties in neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I am a beginner in neo4j and have this neo4j query.

```
MATCH(n:%s:%s)-[:ContainsDish]->(d:Dish:%s) 
            RETURN DISTINCT {Dish: d}
```

Here Suppose Dish has property called Name and is of format id : {name: x, val: y} ....My aim is to return the dishes in sorted order based on name

I tried using order by and apoc.call.sort(d) but those didnt work and I dont have much Idea too in writing neo4j queries so can someone please help

Comment: what is the result you are getting? what is the value of %s? why is it repeated in var n? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably shouldn't store properties as stringified JSON. However, you can probably utilize APOC.

```
MATCH(n:%s:%s)-[:ContainsDish]->(d:Dish:%s) 
WITH distinct d, apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(d.id).name AS name
ORDER BY name
RETURN {Dish: d}
```